SSIS data de SQL Server a un Excel respetando tipo de campos
Hola estoy usando Visual Studio Community 2019, específicamente SSIS. tengo una tarea de flujo de datos donde obtengo los registros de una tabla de SQL Server usando Origen de OLE DB y lo exporto a un archivo Excel.
Todo sale bien, pero el problema es que no respeta el tipo de campo considerando a todos como Texto incluido los números. Para bypassear, he creado una fila dummy con los formatos del archivo, por lo que hasta allí cumple el propósito.
Mi pregunta es como generar este proceso sin este registro dummy?. He probado con las herramientas de Data Conversion y Derived Column.


Tienes que cambiar el tipo de datos en tu destino. De nada sirve que conviertas los datos, si está configurado para recibirlos como texto.
